# Navigating to the previously visible card in a CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, cardlayout

I have a form with a `CardLayout`. In this layout, I have lot of cards. Everything went fine until I had to create a way to "move to the previous xcarsd" by using a button xclixck. CardLayout's default `next()` and `back()` are useless as I don't know how the user is going to lands in a particular card.

So I tried to manage a list of cards being navigated, and move back of the list when the button is clicked. Below is my implementation.

```
  private List<String> goBackListHolder = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int firstPage = 0;

//Listeners
    private class AddNewClientsBtnAction extends MouseAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            CardLayout card = (CardLayout)mainPanelHolder.getLayout();
            card.show(mainPanelHolder, "new_client_form");
            goBackListHolder.add("new_client_form");
            firstPage++;
        }
    }

    private class AddProviderBtnAction extends MouseAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            CardLayout card = (CardLayout)mainPanelHolder.getLayout();
            card.show(mainPanelHolder, "new_provider_form");
            goBackListHolder.add("new_provider_form");
            firstPage++;
        }
    }

    private class AddIntroducerBtnAction extends MouseAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            CardLayout card = (CardLayout)mainPanelHolder.getLayout();
            card.show(mainPanelHolder, "new_introducer_form");
            goBackListHolder.add("new_introducer_form");
            firstPage++;
        }
    }

    private class AddIntroducerBtnAction2 extends MouseAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            CardLayout card = (CardLayout)mainPanelHolder.getLayout();
            card.show(mainPanelHolder, "new_introducer_form");
            goBackListHolder.add("new_introducer_form");
            firstPage++;
        }
    }


// The listener of the Back Button

    private class GoBackBtnAction extends MouseAdapter
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                if(firstPage==0){}
                else
                {
                CardLayout card = (CardLayout)mainPanelHolder.getLayout();
                firstPage--;
                card.show(mainPanelHolder, goBackListHolder.get(firstPage));

                }
            }
        }
```

This works, but after sometime it breaks, moves to incorrect places. Above code is not the complete one, because there is a massive number o listeners.

So, any ideas about how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go back a card, you also have to remove the card you were just on from the end of the list.

Say you went to a new client form:

```
+---------------+
|new_client_form|
+---------------+
firstPage == 1 <- this is already wrong. List is indexed at 0.
```

Then you go to new provider form:

```
+---------------+   +-----------------+
|new_client_form|-->|new_provider_form|
+---------------+   +-----------------+
firstPage == 2
```

Now if you go back:

```
+---------------+   +-----------------+
|new_client_form|-->|new_provider_form|
+---------------+   +-----------------+
firstPage == 1
```

And forward again:

```
+---------------+   +-----------------+   +-------------------+
|new_client_form|-->|new_provider_form|-->|new_introducer_form|
+---------------+   +-----------------+   +-------------------+
firstPage == 2
```

You can see that `firstPage` is now way off.

I would suggest using a [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) instead of a list. Then you can `push()` when you go forward, and `pop()` when you go back. `pop()` will take the top element off the stack and give it to you, so you won't have to keep track of the index. However, make sure you don't push a card onto the stack until you *leave* that page, going *forward*. Otherwise, if you push a card when you arrive at it, you will get that same card when you try to go back, and you will be stuck where you are.

Here's another example with a `Stack`:

Go to new client form:

```
//Empty stack
```

Go to new provider form:

```
+-----------------+
| new_client_form |
+-----------------+
```

Go to new introducer form:

```
+-------------------+
| new_provider_form |
+-------------------+
|  new_client_form  |
+-------------------+
```

Go to new client form again:

```
+---------------------+
| new_introducer_form |
+---------------------+
|  new_provider_form  |
+---------------------+
|   new_client_form   |
+---------------------+
```

Go back:

```
+-------------------+
| new_provider_form |
+-------------------+
|  new_client_form  |
+-------------------+
//Here you get the new_introducer_form passed back
```

Go back again:

```
+-----------------+
| new_client_form |
+-----------------+
// Here you get the new_provider_form passed back.
```

Go back again:

```
//Empty stack.
//Here you get the new_client_form passed back.
```

Answer (score 2):

> but after sometime it breaks, moves to incorrect places

Hard to debug random problems, so the solution is to remove potential for error.

> Above code is not the complete one, because there is a massive number o listeners.

Maybe you have incorrect code in one of the listeners. That is maybe you have a typo for a card name which is causing problems.

Based on the code posted you always move to a different card by using the `show(xxx)` method.

So instead of adding your custom code to your ActionListeners, I would extend `CardLayout` and add your custom code. That is I would override the `show(...)` method to keep track of the card you want to display. So every time the `show(...)` method is invoked you add the card name to your ArrayList.

You would also want to add an `undoCard(...)` method to the extended CardLayout to move back to the previous card. Keep all the logic in one place.

> and move back of the list when the button is clicked

I can't tell if you requirement is to only go back, or do you also need the ability to go forward?

If you only need to go back, then you don't need the "firstPage" variable. To go to the previous card you would just remove the last entry from the ArrayList and then go to the card that is now the last entry in the ArrayList.

Anyway, the main point of this suggestion is that by moving the code to a customized CardLayout, you minimize the need for coding in your application which will also minimize the potential for mistake.